# Defining something within an ArrayFormula which is then used in the ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Thanks for taking some time out of your day.

So I have this code:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(Z$3:Z$294>Q349; IF(AB$3:AB$294>0; 0; IF(Z$3:Z$294>Q349; Y$3:Y$294-(F$3:F$294*Y$1); 0))))-(SUM(IF((J$3:J$294>0)*(Z$3:Z$294>Q349); F$3:F$294; 0))))
```

And I know this won’t work but it should be this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(Z$3:Z$294>Q349; IF(AB$3:AB$294>0; 0; IF(Z$3:Z$294>Q349; Y$3:Y$294-(F$3:F$294*Y$1); 0))))-(SUM(AB$3:AB$294=IF((J$3:J$294>0)*(Z$3:Z$294>Q349); F$3:F$294; 0))))
```

I want to fill

```
AB$3:AB$294
```

With

```
IF((J$3:J$294>0)*(Z$3:Z$294>Q349); F$3:F$294; 0))))
```

But the tricky thing for me is, the fact that

```
AB$3:AB$294
```

Is used in the first part:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(Z$3:Z$294>Q349; IF(AB$3:AB$294>0; 0; IF(Z$3:Z$294>Q349; Y$3:Y$294-(F$3:F$294*Y$1); 0)))
```

So I need a way to fill the array and use the values from that array within the same formula.

If somebody could help that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sorry, it is public

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(BYCOL(IF(R2:R19>TRANSPOSE(K24:K74);
 IF(IF((H2:H19>0)*(R2:R19>TRANSPOSE(K24:K74)); D2:D19; 0)>0; 0;
 IF(R2:R19>TRANSPOSE(K24:K74); Q2:Q19-(D2:D19*TRANSPOSE(K24:K74)); 0)); 0);
 LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))-BYCOL(IF((H2:H19>0)*(R2:R19>TRANSPOSE(K24:K74)); D2:D19; 0); 
 LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Incredible, it’s a really interesting formula. Thanks allot for taking the time!